# setcookie() on jquery get() request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies, get

My problem is that the cookie won't set. I tried removing the `/` in the `setcookie` function but it changes nothing. Also, the path is correct. If I `echo` something after the `setcookie` line, and I `alert` the data in the javascript function, the echo works.

index.php:

```
$.get('inserts/queries?q=1', function(data) {
    undisplay('cookiesMenu');
});
```

inserts/queries.php:

```
if ($_GET['q'] == 1)
{
    setcookie('cookies', '', time() + 3600 * 24 * 365, '/');
}
```

Comment: i would suggest to set the cookie in your javascript. you can probably return a success response for your ajax call and set it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @carloliwanag ! Didn't know creating a cookie in JS was possible.
It did the trick!

```
document.cookie = "cookies=; expires=Sun, 31 Dec 2017 12:00:00 UTC";
```